# How to manually log to Ray Train's internal Tensorboard logger?

Tags: python, tensorboard, ray, ray-tune, tensorboardx

Ray Train automatically stores various things to Tensorboard. In addition, I want to log custom histograms, images, PR curves, scalars, etc. How do I access Ray Train's internal TBXLogger so that I can log additional things?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ray team member here.
What ray train version are you using?
I don't think we currently have an end to end example to showcase how to do this. But you should be able to have something like `tf.summary.image` in your training function. Note this would log images per training worker.

Comment: Currently Ray 2.2.0. Our stack is Pytorch and don't have tf in our requirements, although tensorboardx is installed via Ray. There isn't a way to get a handle to the  summary writer?

Comment: ah i see. Could you use this in your training function? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html

Comment: multiple SummaryWriters are not supported, so I would need to get Ray's SummaryWriter. See this related comment on the Ray issue tracker: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/4762#issuecomment-491501357

Comment: Can we scope each SummaryWriter to each train worker rank? Say if you have 4 workers, they will have their separate local path to work with and there shouldn't be multiple SummaryWriters pointing to the same folder issue.